# Fixed object allowing horizontal movement

Tags: html, css

This one is kind hard to explain. I have a website that has a fixed object on the page.
For most cases this would be fine but now a days with mobile devices it creates a problem.
When ever someone zooms in on the website the fixed object becomes out of line.

Is there a way to make the object move on a horizontal bases while being locked in a vertical position on the screen?

[Original Website](http://srtweert.nl/)

The objects CSS

```
#sidebar{
    width: 250px;
    height: 325px;
    background: url(../../uploads/SRTWeert/sidebar.png) no-repeat 50px 45px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

The HTML

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="bg">
<img src="uploads/SRTWeert/background.png" alt="background" id="background">
</div>

<div id="contentBlock">
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="main"></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force this div to stay on the screen with the top and left property.

Per example :

```
top: 20%;
left: 0;
```

Will force the div to always stay on the left and 20% from top. (must have fixed or absolute position).

It this what you wanted ?

Comment: Nope, try open the website as an example. Zoom in or make your screen really small then use the horizontal scroll you will see